# Flutter: Is there a way to draw partial circles?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I want to be able to enter an azimuth range, let's say: 180 to 240, and draw a partial circle for that range. Much like a piece of pie. Is there a way to do this? Perhaps by turning the rest of the circle transparent somehow? Here's how I draw full circles:

```
  Future<void> _makeCircles() async {
    GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
    double n3 = double.parse(text);
    double n1 = double.parse(text2);
    double n2 = double.parse(text3);

    setState(() {
      for (var i = 0; i < "test".length; i++) {
        var circleIdVal = UniqueKey();
        final CircleId circleId = CircleId(circleIdVal.toString());
        final Circle circle = Circle(
          circleId: circleId,
          center: LatLng(
            n1,
            n2,
          ),
          radius: n3,
          consumeTapEvents: true,
          strokeWidth: 5,
          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(52, 235, 186, .04),
          strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, .2),
        );
```

Comment: check this out https://medium.com/flutteropen/canvas-tutorial-04-how-to-draw-a-pie-chart-and-with-a-round-angle-in-the-flutter-8a22126704f4

Comment: I don't think this can be implemented into Google maps.